# Python OOP output is wrong, any ideas why?

Tags: python, oop

I work on a bigger project, and i ran into this problem. Why the output of this is 2,3 instead of 2,2?

```
class Pos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 0

class Snake:
    snake = []

    def __init__(self):
        for h in range(0, 100):
            self.snake.append(Pos())

    def add(self):
        self.snake[0].x += 1
        print(self.snake[0].x)


snakes = []
j = 2

for i in range(0, j):
    snakes.append(Snake())

for i, snk in enumerate(snakes):
    snakes[i].add()  # || snk.add()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `snake` list an object attribute should do the trick.

```
class Pos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 0

class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.snake = []

        for h in range(0, 100):
            self.snake.append(Pos())

    def add(self):
        self.snake[0].x += 1
        print(self.snake[0].x)


Snakes = []
j = 2

for i in range(0, j):
    Snakes.append(Snake())

for i, snk in enumerate(Snakes):
    Snakes[i].add()  # || snk.add()

# print(Snakes[0].snake[0].x)
# print(Snakes[1].snake[0].x)
```

Comment: I have a list of objects(Snakes) and i want for each object have a list("snake"). And for each object i want to increment the value of snake[0].x. For example: Snakes[0].snake[0].x += 1, Snakes[1].snake[0].x += 1 , Snakes[2].snake[0].x += 1, ...

Comment: @LionMan, in the list objects(Snakes), you have only 2 objects since the value of j is 2. So, you can't access snakes Snakes[2] and so on.

Comment: @LionMan, please rephrase your question so that I can understand what output you are expecting.

Comment: It was an example "j=2", i want to be able to do: Snakes[0].snake[0].x +=1 and Snakes[1].snake[0].x += 1, and both be 2, not Snakes[0].snake[0].x == 2 and Snakes[1].snake[0].x == 3

Comment: @LionMan, I have updated the code. The issue here was that you had made the ```snake``` list a class attribute.